# how to generate a column for a file matches with unique characters in the file name?

Tags: text-processing

I have a bunch of files

```
an_ar_chrom10_pos1_sun_td.txt
an_ar_chrom11_pos1_sun_td.txt
an_ar_chrom13_pos1_sun_td.txt
an_ar_chrom17_pos1_sun_td.txt
an_ar_chrom17_pos2_sun_td.txt
...
```

and each file has similar format looks like this

```
head an_ar_chrom10_pos1_sun_td.txt
    "region" "start" "stop" "mid" "G1_TD" "G2_TD" "G3_TD" "G4_TD"
    "45000002 - 45010001 " 45000002 45010001 90.010003 NA NA NA NA
    "45010002 - 45020001 " 45010002 45020001 90.030003 -1.19087678772119 -0.947895467698369 -0.724767209958411 -0.957244005901499
    "45020002 - 45030001 " 45020002 45030001 90.050003 NA NA NA NA
    "45030002 - 45040001 " 45030002 45040001 90.070003 NA NA NA NA
```

I want to add an extra column to each file based on some unique characters in each file name (e.g chrom10_pos1 for the first file, chrom11_pos1 for the second file, etc

This is my desired out put

```
head an_ar_chrom10_pos1_sun_td_with_id.txt
"region" "start" "stop" "mid" "G1_TD" "G2_TD" "G3_TD" "G4_TD" "ID_
"45000002 - 45010001 " 45000002 45010001 90.010003 NA NA NA NA chrom10_pos1
"45010002 - 45020001 " 45010002 45020001 90.030003 -1.19087678772119 chrom10_pos1-0.947895467698369 -0.724767209958411 -0.957244005901499 chrom10_pos1
"45020002 - 45030001 " 45020002 45030001 90.050003 NA NA NA NA chrom10_pos1
"45030002 - 45040001 " 45030002 45040001 90.070003 NA NA NA NA chrom10_pos1
```

Comment: What is the rule that you would use to extract the desired  "chrom10_pos1" from the filenames? The 3rd and 4th values separated by underscores?  Also, is the new header value `"ID"`?  Also, are the values separated by spaces or tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it with a scriptable editor and a shell loop over the filenames:

```sh
for f in *.txt
do
  value=$(printf '%s' "$f" | cut -d_ -f 3-4)
  printf '%s\n' '1s/$/ "ID"/' '2,$s/$/ '"$value"'/' 'wq' | ed -s "$f"
done
```

This loops over all of the "*.txt" files in your current directory and edits them. The first line in the loop extracts the desired data from the filename into a variable. The second line prints three commands to `ed`:

1. `1s/$/ "ID"/` -- change line 1 to append the new column header
2. `2,$s/$/ $value/` (simplified from the quoted value) -- on lines two through the end of the file, replace the end of the line with a space and the desired data.
3. `wq` -- write the file to disk and quit